# Groovy Elvis and Ternary operator usage

Tags: groovy

This question is about the code behaviour I observed. I have given 3 cases.

```
def data = [:] // some map with data that has map values
def tag = "Some String from Config"
def results = []

// A) This worked
if(data."$tag") {
  // need first key of the inner map
  results << data."$tag".keySet().toArray()[0] ?: 0
} else {
  results << 0
}

//B) Did not work
results << data."$tag" ? (data."$tag".keySet().toArray()[0] ?: 0) : 0 // Gave Null pointer exception


//C) Did not work
results << data."$tag" ?.keySet().toArray()[0] ?: 0 // Gave Null pointer exception
```

I am not sure why but this behaviour I observed. Ideally B and C statements should also work like A. Am I missing something here ? What is wrong ?

Groovy version : 2.2.2
Java : 7

Comment: does it work if you use `complets << (...)`?

Comment: Pedant alert: Thats the Groovy *Elvis* operator. The ternary operator exists in groovy and java and needs two different arguments after the question mark on either side of the colon. It's called the elvis operator because if you turn `?:` on its side it's an elvis emoticon

Comment: @cfrick No I tried. But <pre> ()  </pre? should not make difference here right ?

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yes you are right, slipped through :) Not sure Pedant though

Comment: but B has both (elvis and ternary)

Comment: @cfric yes :) Not sure what to title the question now.

Comment: @cfrick true! Didn't notice that while I was too busy being pedantic

Comment: does the stracktrace indicate where the NPE comes from?  trivial tests gave me no problem regardless of order etc. with 2.3 and 2.2 groovy.

Comment: `result << (data."$tag"?.keySet()?.first() ?: 0)` gives me `[0]` for `result` and without the `()` i get `[null]`.  i'd say its a precedence problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*B* and *C* fail due to the precedence of the operators (`. .?` (dots) > `<<` > `?:`; see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2535-Control *Operator Overloading* -- sorry found no better reference).

```
def data = [:]
def tag = "sometag"

def r1 = []
r1 << data."$tag"?.keySet()?.first() ?: 0
// implies (r1 << data."$tag"?.keySet()?.first()) ?: 0
assert r1==[null]

def r2 = []
r2 << (data."$tag"?.keySet()?.first() ?: 0)
assert r2==[0]
```